# Using Bootstrap Tabs with Angular Formly

Tags: angular-formly

Is there a way to include a "tab" structure in the formly json structure to build bootstrap-ui tabs easily? For example something kind of like this:

```
{
  Tabs: [
    {
      heading: 'Tab 1',
      fields: [
               ....
              ]
    },
    {
      heading: 'Tab 2',
      fields: [
               ....
              ]
    },
  ]
}
```

Is there an easy easy to build this type of structure? Or should I do an ng-repeat on the tabs array with formly inside the ng-repeat? Or are their performance concerns with that or any other concerns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend not putting the tabs in formly. Rather, put formly in tabs. If you're using [angular-ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs), it'd be structured something like this:

```
<tabset>
  <tab>
    <formly-form></formly-form>
  </tab>
  <tab>
    <formly-form></formly-form>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

They can even share the same model. And you could do an `ng-repeat` on the tabs with an array of arrays of formly field configurations. If you like, you can [request an actual example](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly-website/issues/new?title=New%20Example:&body=I%20would%20like%20an%20example%20that%20demonstrates:) of this on [the website repo](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly)

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was thinking. I had written my own dynamic form a while back that took in account the tabs, but then I found formly. 

Are there any special considerations with multiple forms and validation?

Comment: @Jonathan wrap them in a single form and validity bubbles up to that form

Comment: This is asked so often I created a gist with my implementation: https://gist.github.com/benoror/c698f70442f107d37e9d

Comment: Thanks for that @benoror. You're right, this gets asked a lot. So I've finally created [an example](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/integrations/ui-bootstrap-tabs)